# Trouble with Typesafe Repositories and activator

Tags: playframework, typesafe

I'm receiving errors of unresolved dependencies, when trying to create a new play framework 2.3 application. I checked the repositories and can't find the dependencies manually.

```
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#build-link;2.3.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#play-exceptions;2.3.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.3.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#jse_2.10;1.0.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#npm_2.10;1.0.0: not found
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe#webdriver_2.10;1.0.0: not found
```

Commands:

- activator new app play-scala
- cd app
- activator run

Comment: I can reproduce this. I haven't found any issues on activator/play issues yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution can be found [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/E6acpxk9930). In short:

> Same here. After I added a second resolver into my project/plugins.sbt the dependencies were successfully resolved.
>
> resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
>
> resolvers += "Typesafe repository mvn" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/maven-releases/"

End.

Comment: This looks like a bad release from Typesafe, let's hope they fix the ivy repositories or the template for the play-scala webapp.

Comment: Please take in consideration that you'll also need to change the property scalaVersion := "2.11.0" from "2.11.2" in build.sbt file.